# PyPDF2 writer function creates blank page

Tags: python, pypdf

Trying to write a function to combine pages in a PDF document. Streaming the output creates a blank page for an unknown reason Here is the test case

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

dr = r"C:\GC"
ldr = dr + r"\12L.pdf"
writer = PdfWriter()

with open(ldr, "rb") as f:
    reader = PdfReader(f)
    page = reader.pages[0]
    writer.add_page(page)
    f.close()

with open(dr + r"\new.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)
    output_stream.close()
```

Edit: I made some changes to my PE and got more information.

```py
writer.write(output_stream)
```

raises the error

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file: C:\GC\12L.pdf
```

I did some troubleshooting with keeping the reader file open and changing syntax to suggestions and I still raise the error.

Comment: you're opening it with "w"("wb") which i'm pretty sure clears it, if you want to just add to it, you can try opening it with "a" for "append"

Comment: Replacing "wb" with "ab" makes a blank page and "a" returns an error

Comment: Don't put the file handle to PdfFileReader. Give it the path directly instead

Comment: Giving the path directly instead makes no change to the result.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: File with the page contents of of the first page of 12L.pdf

Comment: Btw, you don't need any of those `.close()` statements. They're just adding unnecessary code.

Comment: have you tried the code with another pdf and checked if it does work?

Comment: I tried a bunch of different PDFs and it doesn't work

Comment: I added an edit to the post with new relevant information

Comment: See my comments below on troubleshooting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a context manager, you don't need to explicitly call `.close()`. Try this:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

dr = r"C:\GC"
ldr = dr + r"\12L.pdf"
writer = PdfWriter()

with open(ldr, "rb") as f:
  reader = PdfReader(f)
  page = reader.pages[0]
  writer.add_page(page)
  
  with open(dr + r"\new.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, thanks for the try

Comment: @SimonNasser what is the issue?

Comment: Output  document isn't the first page, but a blank one

Comment: @SimonNasser can you add your updated approach to the question? Also, have you tried `print(in1)` to check if you're actually getting the page and it isn't null?

Comment: in1 is a dictionary: `{'/Type': '/Page', '/Parent': IndirectObject(1, 0), '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 556, 720], '/Resources': {'/XObject': {'/img6': <PyPDF2.generic.NullObject object at 0x0000015C3C78ECA0>}}, '/Contents': <PyPDF2.generic.NullObject object at 0x0000015C3C77DBE0>}`

Comment: @SimonNasser which language is the PDF in? Does the page contain any specific resources that might be causing an issue?

Comment: PDF is in English. Only recourse on the page is an image

Comment: I added an edit to the post with new relevant information

Comment: @SimonNasser have you tried this correctly? The file isn't closed before the `write` operation, I can't see how this would raise an error

Answer (score 1):

The code below opens a PDF file that has 12 pages, gets the first page and writes that page to a new PDF file.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

input_pdf = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
writer = PdfFileWriter()

reader = PdfFileReader(input_pdf)
in1 = writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
input_pdf.close()

output_pdf = open('new_test.pdf', 'wb')
writer.write(output_pdf)
output_pdf.close()
```

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     Apple
OS Version:   macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Python Version: 3.9
PyPDF2 Version: 1.26.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: i don't know why the same exact code is working in your environment and not mine. What operating system and PE are you using?

Comment: I added that information to my answer.

Comment: I added an edit to the post with new relevant information

Comment: @SimonNasser - That ValueError is either related to the indentation of line `with open(dr + r"\new.pdf", "wb") as outputStream` or this `f.close()` being called before the write operation.  Comment out `f.close()` and see if you get the same error

Comment: I address this in an edit b/c code formats badly in comment

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex PyPDF2 recently got a lot of updates. We're now at PyPDF2==2.0.0 :-) The interface was made simpler + PEP8 complient, e.g. PdfFileReader is now PdfReader and `reader.getPage(0)` is now `reader.pages[0]`.

Comment: @MartinThoma thanks for the info.  I need to refresh out my test environment more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works. Not using the open() as f syntax wouldn't initalize the fields of the writer object. Closing the file before the output being written would produce an error. I guess the file must be open so the object can point to the instance.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

dr = r"C:\GC"
ldr = dr + r"\pgSrc\12L.pdf"
rdr = dr + r"\pgSrc\12R.pdf"
r5 = dr + r"\pgSrc\pg5R.pdf"
writer = PdfFileWriter()
with open(ldr, "rb") as f:
  reader = PdfFileReader(f)
  page = reader.getPage(5)
  writer.addPage(page)
  with open(dr + r"\new.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    writer.write(outputStream)
```

Comment: How is this different from my solution?

Comment: Wow it isn't. I wonder what I missed when implementing your solution earlier